# Configuring web.config in Service Stack 3.9 not working

Tags: web-services, servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I'm following a tutorial ServiceStack but I use version 3.9.71 and modify the web.config gives me error. My code is like this:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 (and above?) -->
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the configuration for **ServiceStack v4**, the documentation for the ServiceStack v3 (BSD) is maintained at: https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/

The [Create your first Service](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice) tutorial shows the valid v3 configuration:

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<!-- Required for IIS 7.0 (and above?) -->
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
    <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Your information was very helpful but the real mistake was that the name of my project was " ServiceStack " and caused conflict